# jQuery dialog and Google Map don't behave correctly after the dialog is closed and re-opened

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to show a dialog with a google map, when the user clicks on a certain button.

On this first load the map is shown correctly. After the user hides the dialog and opnes it again, the map is not centered, but moved to the left upper corner.

See this fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/KHctC/5/

How can I fix this?

Comment: funny: ever tried to click 'Show Map' again when it is actually open :)

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair, it does, but not in the right place. Is not centered.

Comment: please ... open the dialog, close it again, open the dialog again and THEN hit the button 'Show Map' again w/o closing the dialog! if you do this (and think about it a bit), you will track the problem: a) maybe not centered b) maybe it needs the location again ... after all: i know problem, and the cause is: google maps does not know the size of the container (as it is actually hidden when being on `open`-event, because it is before opening)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have to use the `setCenter` method if the map is already created.

Please see [this jsFiddle fork](http://jsfiddle.net/F3HP2/).